# karma chrome error in Angular 5 project

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an angular 5 project, this is my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.101",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
```

But when I run ng test I get the following error:

```
17 08 2018 15:46:34.572:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.4.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
17 08 2018 15:46:34.572:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
17 08 2018 15:46:34.576:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome  
17 08 2018 15:46:53.736:INFO [Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket S9ZLPP9j7OZX5GskAAAA with id 46717702
Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
    {
         "isTrusted": true
     }
```

Comment: try to add more detail Error log...

Comment: @ganesh045 this is all I have

Comment: Hmm.. Perhaps trying running ng test with `ng test -sm=false`

Comment: @SSHThis didn't help

Comment: Try logging in your component, like in the constructor add `console.log(" we made it to the constructor")` then keep adding logs until you get to the failure, if you don't even make it to the constructor then the component must not be getting instantiated properly.